# Finding the limit distribution

Tags: probability

It's an old exam problem:

Let $\{\xi_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d with finite variance $\sigma^2$ and $\eta_n=\xi_n+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq1$. What is the limit distribution of $\frac{\eta_1+...+\eta_n-E(\eta_1+...+\eta_n)}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$?

I tried to use Lindeberg-Feller theorem by defining $X_{0,n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\xi_0-E(\xi_0)}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$, $X_{m,n}=\frac{3}{2}\frac{\xi_i-E(\xi_i)}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ for $1\leq m\leq n-1$, and $X_{n,n}=\frac{\xi_n-E(\xi_n)}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$. Then $E(X_{m,n})=0$ and $\sum_{m=1}^{n}E(X_{m,n}^2)\rightarrow\frac{9}{4}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. However, I have trouble showing $\sum_{m=1}^{n}E(X_{m,n}^2:|X_{m,n}|>\epsilon)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. It could be seen that $P(|X_{m,n}|>\epsilon)\leq\frac{E(X_{n,m}^2 )}{\epsilon^2 }\leq \frac{3}{\epsilon^2 n}\rightarrow 0$ and $X_{m,n}$ should go to 0 almost surely, but I don't know how to deal with the sum in front of it. Could it be done in this way? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_i=\sum_{i=1}^n [\xi_i+(1/2) \xi_{i-1}]=\xi_n+(1/2)\xi_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3/2) \xi_i$. Since $\xi_n,\xi_1$ have finite mean and variance, their contribution goes to 0. So you're left with:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3/2)\xi_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3/2)E[\xi_i]}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}+O(1/\sqrt{n}).$$

Now just use the CLT, possibly after some minor adjustments.

Comment: nice, it should be $\xi_n+\frac{1}{2}\xi_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3/2) \xi_i$ though